# Ignore properties dynamically at time of mapping using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper in my .net-core application to create DTOs from my Nhibernate entities to send to the client as a JSON. However, there are some requests that I need to omit certain properties on my entity. For example, assume I have the following classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDTO
{
    public ICollection<FriendDTO> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

Now, there are cases where I need to send to the client a Person with all of their friends, however sometimes I just need the person. I have a automapper configuration that defines a simple mapping between Person and PersonDTO with no omitted properties because that's the most common case. However, rather than create two separate DTOS (one with the Friends property mapped and the other with it ignored), it would be nice to somehow specify this at the time of mapping. I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var personDtoWithoutFriends = _mapper.map<Person, PersonDTO>(person,
    opts => opts.ConfigureMap()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Friends, act => act.Ignore()))
```

I know I can solve this problem with multiple DTOs, however this is an extremely common pattern in my application and I would end up creating a large number of DTOs. Ignoring certain properties in the few cases I need to seems like a much more elegant solution. Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible using AutoMapper?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for you but what about creating two different mappers, one for mapping with friends and one for mapping without and switch between the two when either is needed?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html